# Is there a way to have two versions of the same Adaptec RAID driver installed on RHEL 5 / CentOS 5?

Tags: raid, linux-kernel, drivers, adaptec

We have an older Adaptec 5805 RAID controller on our CentOS 5 server. (I added RHEL 5 to the question because of the similarity in these Linux distributions.) An Adaptec 8805 controller was recently added, but it is not detected by even a recent version v.3.03 of Adaptec's command line utility `arcconf`.

The reason it is not detected is that the currently installed AACRAID driver from Adaptec is version 1.1.5, but the first driver version that supports the new Adaptec 8805 on RHEL 5 is v1.2.1-40300.

This is complicated by the latest driver version that supports the older Adaptec 5805 being 1.1.7-29100.

It looks like to use both RAID controllers at the same time, two versions of the same driver (which is in form of a kernel module) needs to be installed.

Is there a safe way to have both versions 1.1.7 and 1.2.1 of Adaptec's RAID controller driver installed? How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux drivers are in the form of kernel modules; if the drivers use the same module name, only *one* can be loaded at time. If they are completely different modules, it should be possible to load both at the same time (but then you have to check that the Adapter user space utility works correctly)

Anyway, CentOS 5 is long out of support, and the same can be said of any server hardware coming with is. I strongly suggest to update your system.

Comment: Thanks! I checked, and it appears that the drivers use the same module name. Would there be a way to rename one of those module names? I suppose it is not as simple as just renaming the file. Would renaming the module in the source code be necessary?

Comment: @Jake it is very unlikely that simply renaming the module will be of any help.